# Symfony 2.8 CollectionType Edit Issue?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Ok, So I have three tables, `Address`, `Clients` & `ClientAddress`.

I have build a AbstractType form for the address table, which points to my address entity, like so

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->setMethod($options['method'])
        ->add('house', TextType::class, ['label' => 'House'])
        ->add('street', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Street'])
        ->add('city', TextType::class, ['label' => 'City']);
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XXXBundle\Entity\Addresses'
    ));
  }
}
```

I then have a AbstractType for my Client Address table, which only has two keys, the `client_id` & `address_id`. Client Address Form is

```
class ClientAddressType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->setMethod($options['method'])
        ->add('clients_address', CollectionType::class,
                                        ['label' => false,
                                         'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
                                         'allow_add' => true
                                        ])

        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save Address',
                                          'attr' => ['class' => 'ButtonForm']
                                         ]);
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XXXBundle\Entity\ClientsAddresses'
    ));
  }
}
```

I then render the `ClientAddress` form like so,

```
{{ form_start(AddAddress, {'attr': {'id': 'ClientAddressForm'}}) }}
       {{ form_errors(AddAddress) }}

       {{ form_row(AddAddress.clients_address.vars.prototype.house) }}
       {{ form_row(AddAddress.clients_address.vars.prototype.street) }}
       {{ form_row(AddAddress.clients_address.vars.prototype.city) }}

{{ form_end(AddAddress) }}
```

I know that collections can be added again and again using JQuery, but I do not want to do that here, there is no point, as the user will not be adding more than one address.

I just want to embed the address form into the client address abstract type and render using twig. This is the only way I know of getting it to work without using JQuery. - If there is a better way, please let me know.

But this works, a little editing to the submitted data, e.g. to save the address (all address in the system have an account ID). The data then saves to the database.

Now my issue is loading that data back into this collection so that the user can edit the address. The edit path points to a new function,

```
    $ClientAddress = $this->getDoctrine()                            
                    ->getRepository('XXXBundle:ClientsAddresses')
                    ->find($id);

    $ClientForm = $this->createForm(ClientAddressType::class,
                                        $ClientAddress);

    $ClientForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($ClientForm->isValid()) {
        dump('vaild!');
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('XXXBundle:Clients\edit_address.html.twig', [
                            'Address' => $ClientForm->createView()
                        ]);
```

This function points to a new twig file, but the form is rendered in the same way, but I get the following error,

```
Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)"
```

Now `ClientAddress` is not setup as an `ArrayCollection`, because, 1. when saving new data is adds errors, 2. I did not think I needed it has the collection was only be one address, no need for an array to hold the data. - please correct me if I am wrong about that!

So how do I get my data to load into the same collection type form that holds my address form inputs, or am I completely wrong and have to use something else?

Please help...

Please try me if I have not explain my question right, I hope I have but please give me time to expand on question if need.

Many thanks.